# java - decrypt a textfile with external key

Tags: java, encryption

I have a program which is encrypting a text file and saves the encoded txt and the key seperatly. Now I try to write the decrypting program which is using the key to decode the file. I read in the key, but it seems I can't really use it like that. Has anyone suggestions for me, or isn't it even possible to do it like this?

```
public class decrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {

        try {
            File fileDir = new File("C:/xxx/key.txt");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir), "UTF-8"));
            String str;

            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            in.close();
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }


        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
        SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`str = in.readLine()` doesn't append text to `str`, but creates a new string containing the next line instead.
You should do the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Then in the while-loop:

```
sb.append(str);
```

And in the end you can get your string content by calling

```
sb.toString()
```

EDIT: Or if it's clearer this way, a more complete example:

```
String line;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
    System.out.println(line);
}

String content = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I will, the website expects me to wait for 3 more minutes until I can, haha

Comment: Can you tell me why I can't use it as a key in `desalgCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sb.toString());` as well?

Comment: The `init()` method wants a `Key` object, not a `String`. You have to make one: `SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(sb.toString().getBytes(), "Base64")` (of course you'll have to change "Base64" if you use something else). And then `desalgCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key)`

Comment: Ah okay, I see!

Answer (score 0):

> decrypt a textfile

Your question already doesn't make sense. The result of encryption is not a text file. So you have no business trying to read it with a `Reader` in the first place.

You need to have a good look at `CipherInputStream`.